# Android gradle: run single test from command line using --tests option not working

Tags: android, testing, gradle, command-line

Android gradle: run single test from command line using --tests option not working. e.g.,

```
gradlew :app:connectedAndroidTest --tests *.testMethodFoo
```

Error

```
Unknown command-line option '--tests'.
```

Android gradle plugin Version 3.6.0.

It is documented: https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line#RunTestsGradle

I have checked other related questions, but they are old.